# What is a PartialEvaluationExceptionExpression and how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have some code with LINQ query using nHibernate and when it executes, it throws a PartialEvaluationExceptionExpression. What exactly does this mean, and what can I do about it?

```
SomeIqueryableNhibernateObject
.Where(x=>...
some expression
&& !Model.date.HasValue ? true : (x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date)
&& some expresion
```

Where Model is:

```
public class Filter
{
   DateTime? date;
}
```

Exception is caused by the false path of the ternary operator:

```
x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date
```

Even if I modify it to:

```
x.fooDate != null && Model.date.HasValue && x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date
```

it still throws the exception.

Comment: Did you look up the documentation for `PartialEvaluationExceptionExpression` to see what it says about what that exception means?

Comment: I was surprised, but I couldn't find any clear information about that exception. For instance this: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/NHibernate/NHibernate/PartialEvaluationExceptionExpression - it doesn't provide any useful information in my opinion.

Comment: The first Google result for me was this: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Remotion.Linq/Remotion.Linq/PartialEvaluationExceptionExpression

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're running code that's getting the value of a `null` object, and so its throwing.  When the query provider tries to translate that query into something that the database can execute it needs to resolve `Model.date.Value.Date` into its value, so that the value can be used in the query.  Since there is no value, the code breaks.

The solution of course is to not inline a check like this into the query itself.  Determine, outside of the context of the query, whether or not you should be adding this check, and then only add it if needed:

```
var query = CreateInitialQuery();
if(Model.date.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date);
```

Here the query provider is only ever given a value to evaluate when there actually is a value to be evaluated.

Comment: The most important thing for me you've written is the part about translation LINQ expression into SQL. I was thinking too much "imperative" so I was surprised why the false path is executed if condition is true. To be honest I've solved the problem before in the  same way, by extracting it like you've written but I still wasn't aware why it doesn't work. Now I understand the cause. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if a Date/Time value is out of range for the database. (A System.DateTime initialized to default is a good example of this.)